# Jquery + html text input and special symbols

Tags: html, jquery, symbols

I've created a simple text input field with for example max chars 5. When someone type `♥ 123` then that should be 5 characters. So heart symbol + space + 1 + 2 + 3 = 5 characters

However when I try to send this input value via some jquery function then suddenly the heart symbol counts as 3 characters.

Why does jquery handle a html symbol as 3 characters? Is that because of the unicode -> `&#x2665;` or any of `\u2665    &#9829; &hearts; %u2665 %E2%99%A5`? I don't get it, all codes are longer then 3 characters.

Secondly is there a way to handle such symbols as just 1 character?

Comment: how are you calculating the length?

Comment: @Juan: Just with val() or length()